# Time Machine backups & OS restore

Tags: osx-lion, operating-systems, time-machine, time, system-recovery

My permissions were all screwed up and after every exhaustible try to change them all back my only solution was a complete restore. So I did a time machine backup onto my external and started restoring or recovery. Which means it will wipe everything. I'm ok with that as long as I can use all my programs again after reinstalling them. Question is I need to drag the files manually, the data files that is, and NOT restore from my Time Machine back up right?